# Top Half of UITableView Header Doesn't Respond - Xcode 7.2 / Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm having a very strange problem that I've been working on for a few days. I have a UITableView and I am defining custom views for each header. They all appear fine (takes a fair pile of tweaking to get everything in the right place though). In the view, I have two buttons, one for expanding/collapsing the rows beneath the section and one for deleting the section. It all works great.

The problem is that only the bottom portion of the header actually responds to taps.​ Actually, it appears that the top 17.5 pixels are unresponsive. I have tried bringing the button subviews to the front. I have tried replacing the buttons with a UITapGestureRecognizer and I have tried putting that in the header itself and in viewDidLoad() and then checking if the area tapped is inside a header.

I have defined the frame of the header to fill the entire visible header area. I have even tried starting at negative locations, assuming it would overflow the header. 
The red background behind the deleteButton is just to show that the area is filling the entire header's visible area. I will remove the red background later.

Still, everything only works IF the bottom section of the header is tapped. I am at a complete loss. Since everything has the same problem, below is only the code for setting up my header, since that's the way I'd rather go. At the bottom is a screenshot so that you can see everything ​looks​ good. Any help would be appreciated.

(As a side note - I have created each cell's view the same way and added the button with the pencil in it on the right to edit the cell's content... It works fine - you can tap the entire 100% height of the cell on the right side and it works. I have compared code and I can't see where it's much different.)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

```
    let headerBar = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()

    var buttonY = CGFloat(0)

    var buttonH = CGFloat(0)

    var xY = CGFloat(0)

    let hLabel = UILabel()

    hLabel.text = prayerListSectionNames[section].uppercaseString

    if section == 0 {

        hLabel.frame = CGRectMake(tablePrayer.frame.origin.x + 20, 14, hLabel.frame.width, 20)

        buttonY = 0

        buttonH = 0

        xY = 12

    } else {

        hLabel.frame = CGRectMake(tablePrayer.frame.origin.x + 20, -8, hLabel.frame.width, 20)

        buttonY = -18

        buttonH = 18

        xY = 10

    }

    hLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)

    hLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    hLabel.sizeToFit()

    headerBar.addSubview(hLabel)

    let deleteButton = UIButton()

    let imgX = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"red white x.png"))

    imgX.frame = CGRectMake(2, xY, 15, 15)

    imgX.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    deleteButton.addSubview(imgX)

    deleteButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"red white x.png")

    let buttonX = tablePrayer.frame.origin.x + tablePrayer.frame.width - 30

    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, 20, buttonH)

    deleteButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

    deleteButton.tag = 20000 + section

    deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: "deleteButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    headerBar.addSubview(deleteButton)

    let toggleShowButton = UIButton()

    toggleShowButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tablePrayer.frame.width - 50, buttonH)

    toggleShowButton.addTarget(self, action: "toggleShowPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    toggleShowButton.tag = 30000 + section

    headerBar.addSubview(toggleShowButton)

    headerBar.bringSubviewToFront(toggleShowButton)

    headerBar.bringSubviewToFront(deleteButton)

return headerBar
```

}

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAAWj.png)

Comment: Did you try using the 3D Debugger view of XCode to see if there is something above the button?

Comment: Yea check with the 'debug view hierarchy' tool to check if there are any transparent views

Comment: I had not checked the 3d Debugger, honestly, because I have no idea what that is... Apparently I missed an important feature in my travels!! However, I just managed to resolve the issue last night and had forgotten to update - the top half of the headers were actually the footers of the previous section, which was weird since I had returned 0 as their height. But after some more searching, I found that returning 0.0001 for the footer height solved the problem.